# Limit number of simultaneously running containers per application in yarn

Tags: java, hadoop, scheduling, distributed-computing, hadoop-yarn

Suppose a yarn application has long-running tasks (running for 1 hour or longer). When a MR job starts, all cluster resources are blocked, at least until one container is finished, which sometimes can take a long time.

Is there a way to limit the number of simultaneously running containers? Something along the lines, *e.g. map.vcores.max* (per NM, or globally). So the other applications are not blocked.

Any ideas?

ps. Hadoop 2.3.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can see you cannot directly limit number of containers. This is only determined by resources. So the best you can do is to limit resources per application.

In accordance to [Fair scheduler documentation](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/FairScheduler.html) you can assign your application to special queue. In this case you can receive configuration which is pretty close to your task - as you can limit memory or cores resource per queue.

Maybe you can switch to different scheduler or even implement custom one but I don't like this way as doing this you step out of well-tested environment and I don't think you really need to do so much work like custom implementation.

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping for something simpler than setting up extra queues, but looks like this is the simplest it can get.

Comment: BTW in some cases it might worth implementing simple scheduler logic with minimal extension of existing one. From first look I wasn't so optimistic about it but now I am somewhat in doubt.

Comment: Also, if you use Spark, you should set FIFO as ordering policy, so driver + workers will be run together (else, you can have ton of Spark driver containers waiting for worker containers .....)

Answer (score 4):

This behaviour/feature can be handled per framework level rather than in YARN.

In Mapreduce, `mapreduce.job.running.map.limit` and `mapreduce.job.running.reduce.limit` can be used to limit the simultaneously running containers. 

In Tez, It can handled using the property `tez.am.vertex.max-task-concurrency`

Related Jira - 
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MAPREDUCE-5583
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TEZ-2914

Comment: I spent days finding this parameter. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

If you are using resource pools, you can limit the number of applications that are running simultaneously in a single pool. While this is not quite what you asked for, it may prove useful.

If you are using Cloudera Manager, looking in the dynamic resource pool configuration.
[image]

If not, checkout http://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.1.3/bk_system-admin-guide/content/setting_application_limits.html

which describes yarn.scheduler.capacity..maximum-applications

Comment: Pay attention, this limits also pending application, so, if you set a small value, you could have some trouble if you submit too much application that should queue.